# What's an appropriate job title for an all-rounder at a charity start-up?

Tags: resume, title

I run a small charity start-up where both I and my employees have a wide range of responsibilities which I don't believe fall under a traditional job title.

Nonetheless I would like to pick a job title both for people's resumes and (more importantly) for hiring future employees. Is there any job title which identifies a 'generic team member'? Ideally it'd "sound good", though I'm not looking for something overly grandiose like those people who list their title as 'General Ninja', etc.

Comment: Have you looked at comparable charities to see how they describe roles in their organization?

Comment: Yes, and I've come up dry - it's hard to find places which explicitly have people who are pure all-rounders on a small team, doing work which doesn't have a traditional label (like it would if we were a pure research or pure fundraising charity).

Comment: Describe a few of the responsibilities, but Administrative assistant, Program Support Technician, Program Analyst or Management Analyst are all things that could in be generalized titles. However, the difference between the admin duties and the analytical ones is pretty great.

Comment: Generic will still fall into some category based on the general nature of the workplace.  Technician is a great generalist title for a hands on type but probably not accurate for someone working in a small start-up charity.

Comment: I've occasionally called myself "utility infielder" when I wss in that sort of position.

Comment: Dogsbody is the correct formal title I think

Comment: @Kilisi, dogsbody has (in this case incorrect) connotations of being very junior.

Comment: @tog22 what about Senior Dogsbody ? To denote a more responsible runaround position, or perhaps Elderly Dogsbody in deference to age?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think before you name the roles, you should define your role and your team's roles in terms of primary and secondary responsibilities. Then try to name the roles based on the prioritization of functions. Even though everyone is a jack-of-all-trades and pitches in to do what's needed, there should be some clear differences in responsibility.

Non-profit roles tend to perform tasks that fall into three buckets:

- **Business Development** - fund-raising, promotion, decision making
- **Administrative** - finances, communication, databases, IT
- **Programs** - implementation, marketing, social media, outreach, volunteer coordination

Comment: would "Program Consultant" fit for your staff? An entry-level person could be a "Program Coordinator".

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Those could fit, though 'Consultant' suggests someone (typically external) brought in to consult on an area of specific expertise. 'Program Coordinator' or, even more generically, 'Program Officer'.

Comment: I like Program coordinator. Alternatively, you could give people the title that equates to what they spend the most time on or that is professionally the more specialized. So someone who is a bookkeeper and admin support might be titled as bookkeeper if that is the highest job he does or admin assistant if it is 80% of what he does.

Comment: @LexieLou I hope you don't mind but I altered the development bucket to be business development given that seems to be the more popular term. Feel  free to revert it back if you feel this dilutes your answer, I won't mind at all!

Answer (score 0):

`Technology generalist` would probably be the first place I would go, but it is something worth talking over with your team. If it *really* doesn't matter to you, it might matter to them. For example, while one person might clean the kitchen, drive people to the airport, and QA code, they may prefer being a QA engineer.